# My vb6 app not running due to msado15.dll missing or registration issue

Tags: vb6

I register `msado15.dll` for my VB6 app in windows XP and app run successfully on windows XP and windows 7.

But when I register msado15.dll for my app in windows 7 then it is not running on both XP and windows 7.

What's the issue in windows 7?

Comment: why is this tagged VBA!? Why don't I see a real programming question being asked?

Comment: You need much more than just `msado15.dll` to install ADO. Check out the latest MDAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Microsoft changed one or more GUIDs of ADO interfaces. They've [released a hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640696) that allows programs linked with ADO on Windows 7 to run on Windows 7 and earlier versions.

Install the hotfix, then recompile your program, and it should work fine.

Comment: Wasn't that fixed ages ago? Any machine updated in the past year or more would have an up-to-date DLL

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 7 SP1 I compile my project by adding in references msado15.dll in Microsoft ActiveX data objects 6.0 library. Now my app will run in all Windows 7 versions(32 or 64bit).

For windows XP i just make a .bat file in which i register msado15.dll .I put it in project and it is working successfully in windows xp as well.